# 0 value for flag parameter in getBroadcast()

Tags: java, android, android-pendingintent, android-broadcast, android-alarms

I'm creating my own reminder app, but now I have a question about the getBroadcast method, and I can't find its answer:

To study and have an example of how to make an alarm, on the web I see that all the people make a PendingIntent in this way:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent_name = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Main_Activity.this, request_code, Intent_name, 0)
```

Now, here's my problem:
seeing the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) I see that there are only these parametres:

- FLAG_ONE_SHOT
- FLAG_NO_CREATE
- FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
- FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
- FLAG_IMMUTABLE
- any of the flags as supported by Intent.fillIn()

I do not see "0" as a possible value of this parameter, so, does it work? If yes, what does it mean? (in the meaning of: what does it do?)

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523349/what-happens-if-you-set-the-flag-on-a-pendingintent-to-0

Comment: 0 means no flags pretty much

Comment: @JRowan Ok; I shouldn't have troubles because for the request code I have a method that generates a random number (and checks thanks to an array list if it already exists or not and it adds it to that array list); I think that "0" should go, do you agree?

Comment: Yeah that should work

Comment: Thanks :) If you make the answer insteaf of the comment I'll mark it :)

Comment: @JRowan I was thinking.. If i set the flag to FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND to be sure? Or it doesn't matter because the intent it's used by the alarmmanager?

Comment: I couldnt tell you

Comment: Thank you anyway :)